# Marketing Cloud Tracking Exports to Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, data-views

I have a multi-business unit marketing cloud setup and I am trying to extract individual email send data to an external website.

I tried to look up querying this data from within automation builder using the dataviews, but some of the tables I need, such as `_JOB`, only pertains to the account the query is run in (the parent in this case).

Since I need send data across all of the business units, I was thinking of using tracking extracts.

My thought was that I create a tracking extract which goes to the safe house, a file transfer moves it to the FTP, the file is unzipped and moved to /import, and then an import file is run to get this tracking data into a data extension within MC. This allows me to see all of the tracking data across the multiple business units so I can utilize it.

My question is about the tracking exports. Is there a way to export this data right into data extensions so I don’t need to have the other FTP steps in there?

My end result is to get the Opens, SendJobs, and Sent all into data extensions.

I will then add another step to join this data against a synchronized data extension to get the specific contact details so I have the full picture of what was sent and who the user is for my external system.

It sounds a bit hack-ish to me, so I am trying to find out if there is a better way.

When I tried dataviews, I wasn’t able to use `ENT._JOBS` since I was in the parent account. You can only query the parent from a child. However, I need the tracking details from all the children so I don’t think I can go that route.

Comment: I would have to check but I believe the dataviews at the EID level have sent data for the child. The Child MID would be located in the OYBAccountID field

Comment: _Open and _Sent date views will definitely give you data from all child BUs right from top level BU. 
_Jobs may not. I encountered this and had to resort to the exact setup (FTP, Import, Export)

Comment: Thanks for confirming - I need to access _jobs in my query so i don’t think that route will work with me, using the data views. I just didn’t know if the whole ftp->import->export was a bit of a messy process but I couldn’t think of any other way. Seems like the API’s need a specific account to be used when authenticating for the token as well.

Comment: The only way to achieving your use case is by using a tracking extract and unzip the file and then import it again.